# Why can't we iterate with *ngFor in a static Array (formArray)

Tags: angular, forms, static, ngfor, formarray

I got a static variable as :

```
static params = new FormArray([]);
```

and i call it this way :

```
<div *ngFor="let param of params; index as i"> ... </div>
```

But i have the following error displayed :

> Property 'params' is a static member of type 'SeeDataFrameComponent'

So why can't we iterate with *ngFor in a static Array (formArray) ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308795/iterating-through-a-formarray-containing-formgroups-with-ngfor

Comment: There are some good answers here for your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193538/how-to-bind-static-variable-of-component-in-html-in-angular-2

Comment: you need iterate over `params.controls`